# External or Internal error can't read last bit trying to run server.php through php.exe

Tags: php

Error message

> Something Error : 'Continue'not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in C\wamp\www_server\server.php on line 142

Full Code

http://pastebin.com/kqKedQgY

Line 142

> ```
>             continue;
> ```

Small Sample Cut of code

```
public function listen($null = null, $ipc = 0)
{
    /* Create Read Array */
        $read = $this->socket;
        foreach($this->users as $user)
        {
            $read[] = $user->sock;
        }
        $except = $read;
    /* Accept / Filter New Connections */
        if(@socket_select($read, $null, $except, null) < 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: The `continue` word should be inside a foreach or a for statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says continue is not inside a loop, I guess you wanted to write `return`

Comment: So where am I putting the return?

Comment: at line 142, remove continue and put return

Comment: at least you fixed this one :P

Comment: Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_ping() in C:\wamp\www\_server\server.php:2938
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\_server\server.php(2926): database->connected()
#1 C:\wamp\www\_server\server.php(37): database->_construct('localhost', 'root', 'password123', 'ixatdb'
#2 C:\wamp\www\_server\server.php(10): iXatServer->_construct()
#3 (main)
thrown in C:\wamp\www\_server\server.php on line 2938

Comment: Line 2938 below
        return @mysqli_ping($this->link) ? true : false;

Comment: Have you enabled mysqli extension? wamp->php->php extensions-> enable `php_mysqli`

Comment: your version of php is?

Comment: php 7.0.9 that is my version

Comment: is your mysqli.reconnect setting ON ? if it is this is a wontfix problem

Comment: Where do I check for the setting?

Comment: It's off :D wooo XD

Comment: So it's not a wont fix problem

Comment: Is this what I am looking for

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect = Off

Comment: yea I don't know what it is then :D

Comment: you could try changin the connected() function with return $this->link

Comment: Confused Ardit Meti do you have skype or something so I can keep in contact to give you a better insight on this as well? :)